# Where am I going wrong when allocating memory in this simple C program?

Tags: c, string, pointers, memory-management, realloc

The goal of the program is to get the user input from the terminal, and then print out the last character of each word the user inputted.

For example, "Hello World" should print out "od".

Here is the code. I am not sure where I am going wrong when I try to resize the char pointer. The code follows.

The issue only occurs when I use -fsanitize=address in the parameters for gcc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *shortened = NULL;
    int i = 1;
    while(argv[i] != NULL)
    {
        shortened = realloc(shortened, 1 * (sizeof(char)));
        int length = strlen(argv[i]);
        char* curWord = argv[i];
        shortened[i-1] = curWord[length -1];
        i++;
    }
    printf("%s\n", shortened);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It works for me.  What are you seeing?  And what platform are you working on?

Comment: `1` is not `i`.

Comment: @Leonard 
I forgot to mention it only gives me an issue when I use the -fsanitize=address parameter when compiling the program. Without that, I had no issues

Comment: Why are you allocating any memory at all? Your input already exists and is already tokenized. You don't need to allocate memory off the heap in order to find the last character in each of argv[1] through argv[argc-1].

Comment: You need an extra byte of space to add a nul terminator for your string, otherwise the printf is going to cause undefined behaviour. Also it's undefined behaviour if you have no arguments, as you try to print NULL.

Comment: @KenY-N I changed my code to  shortened = realloc(shortened, i+1); to handle this, but -fsantize=address is still giving me a buffer overflow error

Comment: You haven't explained why you're calling realloc() at all.

Comment: @torstenvl In this instance, I actually was able to modify the code to not need realloc at all, you were correct. However, I am writing another program where I do need to use realloc, and I am still having the same issue as I am here.

Comment: Recommend you start a new question with a code sample for the issue you're now experiencing.

Answer (score 2):

You want to realloc `i` characters, plus one for the null terminator, so change this (which allocates just one character):

```
shortened = realloc(shortened, 1 * (sizeof(char)));
```

to this:

```
shortened = realloc(shortened, (i + 1) * (sizeof(char)));
```

Comment: I changed my code to reflect that, now knowing that realloc changes total amount of space, not how much space to add. However, when I use -fsanitize=address, I am still getting the memory buffer issue.

Comment: @ColinNull have you tried to append a null terminator before printf? Anyway, why don’t you allocate shortened as array of argv char at the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Your call to realloc allways allocates only one character.  Don't you want I characters?
    realloc(sizeof(char)*(1+i));

Comment: `sizeof (char)` is 1 by definition.

Comment: @melpomene  Sure, but the OP used sizeof(char).  The interesting thing is the inclusion of i

Comment: @melpomene I know a char is one, I just had that in there to be 100% positive that was not the issue causing my crash.

Answer (score 0):

First, to answer your question - `realloc` gets as second argument the new size, not the increase in size. You need to use the counting of how many words did you have, and change the size accordingly.

Second, `argv` contains the command line arguments, meaning the tokens written after executable name. To get input from the user you might want to use `scanf`.

Comment: `argv[argc]` is guaranteed to be `NULL`.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I remembered the opposite. Why is `argc` given then?

Comment: That's the way I intended to get input from the user. Normally, I would use scanf, but in this instance, we were supposed to get via input after the executable name.

Comment: @ColinNull Oh, Ok.

Comment: @Neo I replaced my previous allocation with shortened = realloc(shortened, i+1); However, using -fsanitize=address for the compiler parameter, I am still getting the memory buffer issue. Did I misunderstand again?